# Daily excel report creation out of MS SQL server query and then export to a file share

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, reporting

I have a simple task. I have a query which needs to be executed in SQL server.
This will be executed daily at least once.
The output of the query execution should be exported in the form of an excel sheet and placed in a file share.
Format of Excel file name should be **dummyExcel_dd-Mon-yy_HH:MM:SS** . Every time code runs it will create a new file.

For example, consider that the query output will have following columns : **EmployeeId** , **EmployeeName**, **Salary**.

What is the easiest way to achieve it in MS SQL Server. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: There's 1,001+ ways to run queries on a scheduled basis. Please tell us more about your environment: what edition of SQL Server is it? Can you use SQL Agent? Do you need "real" Excel OOXML files or is CSV fine?

Comment: "What is the easiest way to achieve it in MS sql server."* SSRS and a data driven subscription? You'll need Enterprise for that. Powershell? An Excel spreadsheet and a human being? There are *loads* of ways to achieve this; what's "easiest" depends on your skill set and the tools you have at your disposal.